# Is there any Queue implementation that restricts the capacity at creation time?

Tags: java, queue, illegalstateexception, deque

Both `ArrayDeque` and `PriorityQueue` work as an `ArrayList` in those terms.. it grows as needed. 
I read that if using `.add(E e)` in a queue which has its capacity full it will throw an  `IllegalStateException`. Is there any implementation (which is not included in the concurrent package)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Feel free to comment your downvote please :)

Answer (score 3):

You can find all of the classes that implement [`Queue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) by looking on its javadoc page. Of those classes, only [`ArrayBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html), [`LinkedBlockingDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html), and [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) can be bounded, but all three are in `java.util.concurrent`.

You will have to implement your own method of keeping the number of elements in your `Queue` below a maximum.

Comment: I had specified " which is not included in the concurrent package. Read the question.

Comment: @Rollerball I'm aware. That's why I said `but all three are in java.util.concurrent`. Read the full answer.